# Qibla compass in Android

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

I have try much but can not make Qibla compass for my application. I can't understand what I do. I need Qibla compass that works perfectly.

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Are you trying to program one?  What are you having trouble with?  What have you tried?

Comment: USE this https://github.com/imranbaigshortcut/android-qibla-finder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You know the location of Mecca and you know the users current location (if you have GPS or some other location provider).  The bearing is given by this formula, latitudes and longitudes should be in radians.

```
float lonDelta = (lon2 - lon1);
float y = Math.sin(lonDelta) * Math.cos(lat2);
float x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lonDelta);
float brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDeg();
```

`brng` is the direction in degrees.

You could also explore the Location.bearingTo() method, [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#bearingTo%28android.location.Location%29).

Comment: I am getting erro: `Cannot invoke toDeg() on the primitive type double`

Comment: Solved it `float brng = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));`

Comment: Use this customizable library

https://github.com/imranbaigshortcut/android-qibla-finder